# Is there a way to speed up grep -v -f?

Tags: grep

I have 2 files, A, with 6 million lines, and B with 5 million lines, I'm trying to get lines that are in A, but are missing from B, with `grep -v -f B A`, but it's very slow. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: is the input data ASCII? you could add `-F` and `-x` options if you are matching whole lines literally (no regex)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418429/find-intersection-of-lines-in-two-files might help

Comment: Related: [Linux tools to treat files as sets and perform set operations on them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11343)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two files are sorted (in the same locale as the current one), use this command.

```
comm -23 A.txt B.txt
```

If they're not sorted and your shell supports ksh-style process substitution:

```
(export LC_ALL=C; comm -23 <(sort A.txt) <(sort B.txt))
```

(`LC_ALL=C` to get a deterministic (and fast) sorting order).

See also the `combine` utility  from `moreutils` that doesn't require files to be sorted:

```
combine A.txt not B.txt
```

Beware it loads the whole files in memory though.

Comment: that assumes input is sorted

Comment: Thanks mate, sorted the files beforehand and it worked instantly

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you need to grep for lines in a file where file1 and file2 don't have identical lines, but file1 contains strings to grep for, you may be able to `sort`, and then use `join`.